# Having trouble with File I/O in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io

Heres my code:

```
 String path = "/data/data/edu.bfit.readwritedemo/files/test.txt";
    FileInputStream fis;
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + path);
    try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader dataIO = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            while((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null)    
                sBuffer.append(strLine + "\n");
            strLine.substring(0,4);
            dataIO.close();
            fis.close();
            Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this, "read successful!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this, "read failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file keeps failing to open. I feel like the issue is with the path and this is where I am confused. I manually created test.txt for testing purposes and stored it in a directory in the root directory of the project. I named this directory files, and this is the path I would like to point to for the file object. Am I going about this all wrong? My main goal is to be able to read in a system file on the Android system and search for a substring. thanks in advance, my apologies for the wall o' text.

Comment: If you plan to have a file packaged with the app (that is, not generated) it's easier to use a `raw` [resource file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: well what I would like to do ultimately is read the data that Android stores in /data/system/wpa_supplicant so that I can single out saved wifi networks

Comment: The device will have to be rooted, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this... This goes to the Downloads folder but you can change that variable to other system variables.

```
File path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File textFile = new File(path, "test.txt");
```